# R: gsub words between space

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have a text that looks like this:

```
a <- "233,236,241 solitude ΔE=1.9"
```

What I want to do is to extract the second word in between two spaces ( ), giving this output

```
> solitude
```

I tried two method:

```
a1 <- strsplit(a,' ',fixed=TRUE)[[1]][2]
a2 <- sapply(strsplit(a, " ", fixed=TRUE), "[", 2)
```

But it always show:

```
ΔE=1.9
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: `strsplit(a,' ')[[1]][2]` works for `a<-"233,236,241 solitude ΔE=1.9"`

Comment: Or maybe just `sub(".*\\s+(.*)\\s+.*", "\\1", a)`

Comment: I get "solitude" with each of your methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
gsub("\\s.+$","",gsub("^.+[[:digit:]]\\s","",a))
```

Comment: What's the point in two `gsub` calls?

Comment: The first one cut the text until the space before "solitude" The second one cut the text from the space after the "solitude" till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using capture classes (patterns inside parentheses) and character classes (patterns inside square brackest).

```
sub("(^[^ ]*[ ])([^ ]*)([ ].*$)" , "\\2", a)
[1] "solitude"
```

Annotating the first capture class pattern:

```
"(^[^ ]*[ ])([^ ]*)([ ].*$)" , "\\2", a)
         \finds first space
       \ an arbitrary number of times
    \\ inside a character class an '^' as the first character ...
       signals negation of character class. This one with only the space character in it.
  \----- '^' marks the beginning of a character value
```

Second capture class pattern:

```
"(^[^ ]*[ ])([^ ]*)([ ].*$)" , "\\2", a)
                 \ an arbitrary number of times
              \\negation of character class with only the space character in it.
```

Third capture class:

```
"(^[^ ]*[ ])([^ ]*)([ ].*$)" , "\\2", a)
                     \ the second space
                        \\anything after second space to end.
```

The `"\\<n>"` entries in the `replacement` refer to the capture class matches n the order they appear in the `pattern` argument.